Connections between singular values and eigenvalues
Recently, I have been learned Furstenberg-Kesten Theorem. I met a problem about singular values and eigenvalues.
Recall that for a $d\times d$ matrix $A$, one can define that the singular values of $A$ are all eigenvalues of $\sqrt{A^{T}A}$, where $A^{T}$ means the transport of $A$. For convenience, we denote $\delta(A)$ by one of singular values of $A$ and eig($A$) by one of eigenvalues of $A$.
Now, I want to know the connections between $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\frac{\ln\delta(A^{n})}{n}$ and ${\rm eig}(A)$. Thanks!

If $A\ne0$, we do have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\frac{\sigma_1(A^n)}{n}=\ln\rho(A)$, although the RHS is the logarithm of the spectral radius of $A$ rather than the logarithm of an eigenvalue of $A$.

Could you give me some hints or references for this result? Thanks!

It is a famous result, known as Gelfand’s formula.
